# Draw nested radicals

Tags: code-golf, math, ascii-art

Many formulas in math involve nested radicals (square root signs inside other square roots signs). Your task here is to draw these using ascii art.

## Specs

You will be given two integers, the number inside the radical, and the number of radicals. I think the best way to explain what you have to do is with an example. Here is the output for `2, 4`:

```
        ____________________
\      /       _______________
 \    /  \    /     __________
  \  /    \  /  \  /   _____
   \/      \/    \/  \/ 2
```

Here are some things to note:

- The height of each radical increases by one
- The length of the `_`'s are always `5` times the height
- There is a space after the last `/` and before the next inner radical starts
- The number inside will never be greater than 4 digits
- If the number of radicals is 0, just output the number
- Putting extra spaces to pad it into a rectangle is up to you
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in **bytes** wins!

## Test Cases

```
2, 4:
        ____________________
\      /       _______________
 \    /  \    /     __________
  \  /    \  /  \  /   _____
   \/      \/    \/  \/ 2

23, 0:
23

4, 1:
  _____
\/ 4

1234, 3:
      _______________
\    /     __________
 \  /  \  /   _____
  \/    \/  \/ 1234
```

Comment: I feel like this would be a slightly better challenge if the horizontal bars all had to end at the same point.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3.5, <s>145</s> 137 bytes

```
def s(n,x):[([print(' '*j+'\\'+'  '*i+'/ '+' '*j,end='')for j in range(x-i-1,-1,-1)],print('  '*i+i*'_____'or n))for i in range(x,-1,-1)]
```

Slightly ungolfed:

```
def s(n,x):
    for i in range(x,-1,-1):
        for j in range(x-i-1,-1,-1):
            print(' '*j+'\\'+'  '*i+'/ '+' '*j,end='')
        print('  '*i+i*'_____' or n)
```

Output:

```
s(2,4)
        ____________________
\      /       _______________
 \    /  \    /     __________
  \  /    \  /  \  /   _____
   \/      \/    \/  \/ 2
```

Comment: `print('  '*i+'_____'*i or n)` saves 7 bytes. EDIT `print('  '*i+i*'_____'or n)` saves 8.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know you could use 'or' like that.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>133</s> <s>132</s> 131 bytes

```js
f=(n,r,q=r)=>~r?'1\\0/1 '[x='repeat'](d=q-r).replace(/\d/g,i=>' '[x](+i?d-=.5:r*2))+(r?' '[x](r*2)+'_'[x](5*r):n)+`
`+f(n,r-1,q):''


F=(n,r)=>console.log( f(n,r) )
F(2,4)
F(23,0)
F(4,1)
F(1234,3)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important;top:0}
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 124 bytes

```js
f=(s,n,i=0,r=(n,c=` `)=>c.repeat(n))=>n?r(n+n)+r(n*5,`_`)+`
`+f(s,n-1).replace(/^/gm,_=>r(i)+`\\${r(n+~i<<1)}/`+r(++i)):s+``
```

```html
<div oninput=o.textContent=f(s.value,+n.value)><input id=s><input id=n type=number min=0><pre id=o>
```

Save 3 bytes if the first parameter can be a string rather than a number.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 178 bytes

```php
for($r=[" $argv[1]"];$i++<$argv[2];$r[]=$p("",2*$i).$p(_,5*$i,_))for($k=-1;++$k<$i;)$r[$k]=($p=str_pad)("\\".$p("",2*$k)."/",2*$i," ",2).$r[$k];echo join("\n",array_reverse($r));
```

bah that´s awfully long.